# React Native Carousel OnPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I followed this tutorial in order to have a slider with images : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAgJqaJc-ck

I have three main files :

Carousel.js

```
 const Carousel = ({data}) => {
        const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0)
        let position = Animated.divide(scrollX, width)
        if (data && data.length){
            return (
                <View>
                    <FlatList data = {data}
                    keyExtractor= {(item, index) => 'key' + index}
                    horizontal
                    pagingEnabled
                    scrollEnabled
                    snapToAlignment = 'center'
                    scrollEventThrottle = {16}
                    decelerationRate = {"fast"}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = {false}
                    renderItem = {({item}) => {
                        return <CarouselItem item= {item} navigation={props.navigation}/>
                    }}
                    onScroll = {Animated.event(
                        [{nativeEvent : {contentOffset: { x : scrollX}}}]
                    )}
                    />
    
                    <View style = {styles.dotView}>
                        {data.map((_, i) => {
                            let opacity = position.interpolate({
                                inputRange : [i - 1, i, i + 1],
                                outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
                                extrapolate : 'clamp'
                            })
                            return <Animated.View 
                            key={i}
                            style = {{opacity, height : 10, width : 10, background: '#595959', margin: 8 , borderRadius: 5}}
                            />
                        })}
    
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }
        console.log('Please provide Images')
        return null
    }
```

CarouselItem.js

```
const CarouselItem = ({item, navigation}) => {
    const url = item.url
    return (
        <View style={styles.cardView} >
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("BoatInfo")}><Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.url}} /></TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.textView}>
                <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.imageDescription}>{item.description}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And Data.js

```
export const dummyData = [
    {
        title: 'BOAT DETAILS', url : require('../component/schema.jpg'), 
        description: 'PDF containing the specificities of the boat', id : 1
    }, 
    {
        title: 'TUTORIALS', url : require('../component/tuto.png'), 
        description: 'Become a capitain by watching these videos', id : 2
    }, 
    {
        title: 'YOUR TRIP', url : require('../component/trip.png'), 
        description: 'Follow your trip details', id : 3
    }, 

]
```

Now, As you see in CarouselItem, I am trying to add a functionality so that when I press on the image, it would take me to another page (each picture takes me to a different page). However, when I try to do so, I get the following error:
[image]

So, I understand that in props it is empty...

But when I switch `const CarouselItem = ({ item }, props) => {` to `const CarouselItem = ( props, { item }) => {`  Then I get the following error:

[image]

What I don't understand is that when I remove {item} then the navigation works and when I remove props then {item} works... How can both work? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

[Only screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/) in React Native automatically have access to the navigation prop, so you'll need to pass it to the CarouselItem component, then use the always fun [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get your particular props in the component (like you did with `item`). It should look like this:

```
...
renderItem = {({item}) => {
    return <CarouselItem item={item} navigation={navigation}/>
}}
...
```

and then:

```
const CarouselItem = ({ item, navigation }) => {
...
```

and that should work!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it says in Carousel that navigation is not defined. What should I do ?

Comment: In your `Carousel` component, try doing `const Carousel = ({data, navigation}) => {...` and then `return <CarouselItem item= {item} navigation={navigation}/>`.

Comment: Still no, it says : TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Comment: Do you definitely have navigation in the app?

Comment: Is there a location for an updated version of the code, that I could pull down and try to play around with? Im currently trying to do roughly the same thing, where I cloned the react-native-snap-carousel and got the example up and running. Now I just want to simply open another stack on click

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass navigation prop object from flatlist with item object too something like this

navigate ={props.navigation} item={item}
in crousal function you have to write like this
crousalItem =(item, navigation) =>
This way you got both item and navigation object.
use item to list data, navigation.navigate() to move to another screen

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with your suggestions but I get navigation is undefined in Carousel.js